# SSMA (SQL Server Migration Assistant for Access) cannot connect to SQL Server

Tags: ms-access, sql-server-2019

[image]

Dear experts , I am trying to use the SSMA SQL Server Migration Assistant for Access to migrate a MS Access 2019 database to MS SQL Server 2019 database. The tool is successfully read the Access database but when i press Connect to SQL Server , the Server name dropdownlist is empty as shown in photo, and the port is default  Database dropdownlist is empty . Which means that the toll cannot recognize SQL server.
Any idea how to solve this problem.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you able to connect to the database in SQL Server Management Studio? If so, manually enter in the server name and default database...

Comment: Thank you very much , it works now

Comment: Kindly , do you know how to make both database are synchronized, i mean when you insert record in Access , it is transferred to SQL

Comment: Kindly how to schedule migration ?

Comment: Well, going from a database migration concept and now jumping to a database synchronization architecture is a MASSIVE and a Mount Everest of a different kind of problem. There are no easy sync providers for Access to SQL server, but then again the migration assistant has ZERO to do with synchronization of data. Typical setups are to migrate the access back end (tables) to sql server, and now link your access front end to sql server. As a result, no synchronization is required - you are updating and working with a live SQL database.